# How to rotate Laravel collection's first place on every refresh?

Tags: laravel

I want to rotate a Laravel collection's first place in every refresh. The goal is every item of the collection to be on first spot.

For example if we have 10 items in the collection on every refresh for the first 10 times I want to see a different post and on the 11th refresh to see the first one again.

So far the only way I got closer to achieving this is by using `inRandomOrder()`, but I want to add order to the randomness and every child inside the collection to be on first in the first 10 refreshes.

`$featured = Post::whereNotNull('subscription_id')->inRandomOrder()->get();`

Comment: Do you need whole collection of 10 elements rotated so it starts with n-th element or you need only n-th element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store current position in cookies or DB

Rotate data using collection methods

In controller:

```
$currentPosition = $this->getCurrentPosition() % $collection->count(); // From cookies, DB or where ever 
$newCollection = $collection->skip($currentPosition)->merge($collection->take($currentPosition));

$this->updateCurrentPosition(); // add +1 to counter
```

Comment: This solution is in case if you need whole collection rotated to n-th element. If You only need n-th element then I can update my answer

Comment: Thank you, I think this is perfect. I will implement it and test out how it rolls.